# Node mailer embed link in text

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to embed a link inside text in node js like below

```
"You can <a href='http://"+ config.clientHost + "/#/rating/" + data._id + "'> click this link</a> or reply to this email using the format below: \n"
```

But at mail it is showing like [image]

How can I convert this url into just 'click this link' in node js while sending email using node mailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send your body in html not in text. Only if you send your html tags in 'html' it will convert otherwise it will be sent as text.